# Connect to rabbitmq on local host from a Docker container

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I have a java app running in a docker container and a rabbitmq running in local host (mac). The app need to communicate with the rabbitmq on local host, could some one point out how could i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Giorgio Thanks for your answer, it showed me the right place to look at. I couldnt get it running with your solution as I am using Docker on Mac and your solution is suitable for Linux environment.

Networing feature for Docker on Mac does not support docker0 interface as explained in  https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

I followed the given solution under the section "I want to connect from a container to a service on the host" of the above link.

Creating an alias on lo0
and adjusting the rabbitmq.config to listen on that IP solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Docker engine provide a virtual network interface as a getway if you use `--net="bridge"`. It's a standard value. On linux you can know the name of the interface with `ifconfig` command.

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 02:42:56:6c:95:26  
      indirizzo inet:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Maschera:255.255.0.0
      indirizzo inet6: fe80::42:56ff:fe6c:9526/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:28267 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:25451 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisioni:0 txqueuelen:0 
      Byte RX:52948314 (52.9 MB)  Byte TX:25718113 (25.7 MB)
```

Inside my container I just use, in this case, **172.17.0.1** as gateway to access to my host.

Inside your container you can also show routes with the `route` command and see what is the default gateway

```
root@15fae92c516f:/# route
 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use      Iface
 default         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0  eth0
 172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0  eth0
root@15fae92c516f:/#
```

Comment: Note that iproute2 is available to query net info in most linux' now `ip link show` `ip address show` `ip route show`